# как выровнять блок по центру bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо сделать форму по центру.
Я пробовал, например, col-lg-2, но он только уменьшал ширину

```html
<form>
  <div class=" mt-3 form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Нужно обернуть всю форму в контейнер нужной ширины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <form>
    <div class=" mt-3 form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
    <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```